# ajax-loading doesn't stop or infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp, for-loop

I'm not sure if it is an ajax issue or if I have an infinite loop, I'm trying to get the values of one page to another.

My 1st page is a cakephp contoller:

```
$arr = ($this->Phone->find('all'));
$arr2 = json_encode($arr);

echo $arr2;
$_GET ['var1'] = $arr2;
die();
```

My 2nd page that gets and displays the output is this one

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="sizeof.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var results;
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://localhost/restdemo/',
                    data: {
                        var1: results
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log('success');
                        var output = JSON.parse(data);

                        for (x = 0; x <= output.length - 1; x++) {
                            var hello = (output[x]["Phone"]["name"]);
                            document.write('<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">');
                            document.write('<tr>');
                            document.write('<td>' + hello + '</td>');
                            document.write('</tr>');
                            document.write('</table>');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>    
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am getting my desired results however the page doesn't stop loading which makes me think that I have an error in my code to cause such an action. What causes this?and how can I fix it?. any feedback, comments and suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Does the chrome dev tool network panel tell you anything?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles chrome dev tool and firebug aren't seeing anything

Comment: I'm getting "Refused to execute script from ...jquery.shuffleLetters.js' because...because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."

Comment: That doesn't look like proper CakePHP to me...